# Suppress missing values in Tabyl xtabs in R

Tags: r, janitor

[According to the tabyl documentation:](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/vignettes/tabyls.html)
[image]

However, I can't figure out how to suppress the NA from the denominator!

Please see here for the data:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,2,2,1, NA,NA),
                 col2 = c("this", NA,"is", "text",NA,NA,'yes'), 
                 col3 = c('TRUE', 'FALSE', NA, 'TRUE','TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE'), 
                 col4 = c(2.5, 4.2, 3.2, NA, 4.2, 3.2,3)) %>% 
                  mutate_if(is.numeric, as.factor) %>% 
                  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) 

str(df)  
df %>% 
  tabyl(col1, col3, show_missing_levels = F) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("row")%>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
  adorn_ns()
```

Note how the percent of the NA is still showing up in the denominator. I don't want to see the NA % at all in the cross tab:

```
 col1      FALSE       TRUE        NA_
    1 33.33% (1) 66.67% (2)  0.00% (0)
    2  0.00% (0) 50.00% (1) 50.00% (1)
 <NA> 50.00% (1) 50.00% (1)  0.00% (0)
```

What I want to see:

```
 col1      FALSE       TRUE       
    1 33.33% (1) 66.67% (2)  
    2  0.00% (0) 100.00% (1)
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `show_na = TRUE` in `tabyl`.  If we change it to `FALSE`, the OP's code should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
 df %>% 
   tabyl(col1, col3, show_missing_levels = FALSE, show_na = FALSE) %>%
   adorn_percentages("row")%>% 
   adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
   adorn_ns()
```

-output

```
#  col1      FALSE        TRUE
#    1 33.33% (1)  66.67% (2)
#    2  0.00% (0) 100.00% (1)
```

---

Earlier, was thinking about injecting `na_omit` to remove the NA rows and `select` to select the columns of interest.  But, this will also changes/remove the attribute, thus making the `adorn_ns` to not work

Comment: I want the NA removed from the denominator, this just hides the NA columns-- for example second column, second row should be 100%, not 50%

Comment: @akrun should it not be `na.omit`?

Comment: was just on the way with the same solution. but you were faster!

Comment: @TarJae it was from `collapse`.  but you could use `na.omit` from `base R`

Comment: Thank you akrun. maybe `digits = 0`?

Comment: @TarJae i think the OP wanted 2 digits rounded as in his expeced

Answer (score 1):

It is almost the same as akrun's

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
df %>% 
  tabyl(col1, col3, show_missing_levels = FALSE) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-NA_) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row")%>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0)
```

Output:

```
 col1 FALSE TRUE
    1   33%  67%
    2    0% 100%
```

Comment: This is close,but I also need to see the N's (please see my desired output)! adorn_ns() %>% does not work with this